# Ignore user input while printing

Tags: bash

I have a bash script in which I print text to the terminal, but for dramatic flair, it happens as if by typewriter, causing the output to print out character by character and takes multiple seconds to print out depending on the length of whatever string I'm printing out. The problem is that while whatever string is printing, users are able to type whatever they desire on the keyboard, which is subsequently printed within whatever string I was trying print.

What I can't figure out: how to ignore user input so at the very least nothing that they type displays while my string is printing. `stty` can't help here, because while `stty -echo` would hide user input, it would also hide the string I was trying to print. `read -s` is also no help since I'm not asking questions.

What do I do? Any and all help appreciated.

Comment: What about `read -s -t`?

Comment: Show us the script. How is `stty -echo` hiding its output?

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no good way in bash to clear the terminal input buffer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `read -s` together with `-t`, i.e. a timeout.

The printing can't be run from the same shell as the `read` as it would run too soon or too late. You can print in a background while `read`ing, though:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
text='Hello world!'
for ((i=0; i<=${#text}; ++i)) ; do
    printf %s "${text:i:1}"
    sleep .2
done &
read -s -t 3
echo
```

But `stty -echo` seems to work just fine:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
text='Hello world!'
stty -echo
for ((i=0; i<=${#text}; ++i)) ; do
    printf %s "${text:i:1}"
    sleep .2
done
echo
stty echo  # Don't forget to turn it back on!
```

Comment: As a bonus, how would I be able to prevent any user input during printing from going into ```$REPLY``` if I did decide to use ```read -p```?

Comment: What do you mean? Just ignore what's in $REPLY. If you need to ask for input later, overwrite the previous value.